# Array.fill expects 1-3 arguments, got 0?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm migrating my react app to typescript and am running into an issue with these blocks of code:

```
const weekNumber = [
    ...Array(CURRENT_WEEK_NUMBER)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => i + 1)
  ];
  const weekLabels = [
    ...Array(17)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => i + 1),
    'Playoffs: Wild Card',
    'Playoffs: Divisional Round',
    'Playoffs: Conference Championship',
    'Playoffs: Super Bowl'
  ];
```

> Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0. An Argument for value was not
> supplied

I understand what this is telling me, but how do I refactor this code or have compiler ignore this?

Comment: You can provide `.fill()` with an arugment `.fill(null)` ...

Comment: Use 0. One character ;).

Comment: You could also use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this: `Array.from({ length: 17 }, (_, i) => i + 1)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Array.fill` takes a value that you want to fill your Array with. By leaving out the parameter, it will be `undefined` at runtime, so to satisfy the compiler and keep the functionality the same, you would need to explicitly pass `undefined`:

```
Array(17)
    .fill(undefined)
    .map((_, i) => i + 1)
```

An alternative solution would be to use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) instead, something like:

```
Array.from({ length: 17 }, (_, i) => i +1)
```